# Wordpress editor don't work if parent has display none when rendered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to open a popup window with text fields and a wp_editor. This is already rendered in the footer but only display none. I will give you my code bellow of what I have tried but none of the work to 100% only to 90% maximum. Both of them have different bugs if we can solve it in one way or another it won't matter.

What I have tried:

**Try one: I init a textarea to the editor and popup window is display none**

**PHP:**

```
_WP_Editors::editor($option["value"], 'pbcontent', array('drag_drop_upload' => true ));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
et_tinyMCEPreInit  */
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    if(typeof( et_tinyMCEPreInit ) == 'undefined') {
        et_tinyMCEPreInit = JSON.stringify(tinyMCEPreInit);
    }
});
</script>
    <?php
```

**Javascript:**

```
var str = et_tinyMCEPreInit;
var ajax_tinymce_init = JSON.parse(et_tinyMCEPreInit);

ajax_tinymce_init.mceInit.pbcontent.plugins = ajax_tinymce_init.mceInit.content.plugins.replace('fullscreen,', '')
ajax_tinymce_init.mceInit.pbcontent.toolbar1 = ajax_tinymce_init.mceInit.content.toolbar1.replace('dfw,', '')
tinymce.get('pbcontent').remove();

console.log(ajax_tinymce_init.mceInit.pbcontent);

tinymce.init( ajax_tinymce_init.mceInit.pbcontent );
```

**Try two: I use the normal wp_editor, and popup window is displayed none.**

**PHP:**

```
wp_editor($content, 'pbcontent'.$module_count);
```

**Javascript:**

```
I have no clue how I could "re-init" the visual editor.
```

In try one it works to edit like normal I only get a console error when I mark text that's already in the editor, and I can't edit what's in the textbox when I try to edit a link, the popup comes up but I can't edit it.
In try two it works 100% if the wp editor is visible when rendered but if rendered with display none on parent it doesn't work at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup on a site that I'm working on currently, using jQuery. My editor is loaded from a different page using AJAX into a div with the class "ajax_editor", then immediately faded out:

```
function loadEditor() {
        $.ajax({url: "post-editor", success: function(result){
                        $('.ajax_editor').addClass('active').html(result).fadeOut(0,function () {
                            $('.header .editor').prop( "disabled", false ).attr("placeholder", "Let us know what you're thinking - post something.");
                        });
                    }});        
    }
```

I then use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to show or hide the editor:

```
function openEditor() {
    $(".ajax_editor").fadeIn(500);
}

function closeEditor() {
    $(".ajax_editor").fadeOut(500);
}
```